# Sunday day in date picker in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, datepicker

I have the following code in javascript:

```
 $.fn.datepicker.dates['es'] = {
    days: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"],
    daysShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Jue", "Vie", "Sáb", "Dom"],
    daysMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sa", "Do"],
    months: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
    monthsShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],        
    today: "Hoy"
    };

    $('.datepicker2').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            language: 'es',
            weekStart: 1,
            todayHighlight: true, 
            daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0",
            autoclose: true        
        }).on("changeDate", function(e) {
        diasem = e.date.getDay();                      
        });


    $('tr.item2').each(function(){        



      var km = parseInt($(this).find(".km").val());
      var hviaje = parseInt($(this).find(".hviaje").val());
      var tohtrab = parseInt($(this).find(".tohtrab").val());
      var hfest = parseInt($(this).find(".hfest").val());
      var htrab = parseInt($(this).find(".htrab").val());
      var medieta = parseInt($(this).find(".medieta").val());
      var dieta = parseInt($(this).find(".dieta").val());
      var hotel = parseInt($(this).find(".hotel").val());     

      if (hviaje>8){               
           calc_tohtrab = (hviaje + tohtrab)-8;
           $(this).find('.hviaje').val("8");
           $(this).find('.tohtrab').val(calc_tohtrab.toFixed(0) );
      }




      calc_hfest = ((hviaje+tohtrab)-8);
      calc_dietas = hviaje+tohtrab;
      calc_htrab = tohtrab - hfest;



      var act_hfest = calc_hfest > 0 ? calc_hfest : 0;
      var act_dietas = calc_dietas >= 8 ? 1 : 0;
      var act_medieta = calc_dietas >= 8 ? 0 : 1;
      var act_htrab = calc_htrab > 0 ? calc_htrab : 0;


      if (diasem===0){
          $(this).find('.hfest').val(" ");
      } else {
          $(this).find('.hfest').val( act_hfest.toFixed(0) );
      }          
      $(this).find('.htrab').val( act_htrab.toFixed(0) );
      $(this).find('.medieta').val( act_medieta.toFixed(0) );
      $(this).find('.dieta').val( act_dietas.toFixed(0) );



      total_km += km > 0 ? km : 0;
      total_hviaje += hviaje > 0 ? hviaje : 0;
      total_hfest += hfest > 0 ? hfest : 0;
      total_htrab += htrab > 0 ? htrab : 0;
      total_medieta += medieta > 0 ? medieta : 0;
      total_dieta += dieta > 0 ? dieta : 0;
      total_hotel += hotel > 0 ? hotel : 0;

    });       




    $( '.total_km' ).text(total_km.toFixed(0));
    $( '.total_km' ).val(total_km.toFixed(0)); // for hidden field


    $( '.total_hviaje' ).text(total_hviaje.toFixed(0));
    $( '.total_hviaje' ).val(total_hviaje.toFixed(0)); // for hidden field


    $( '.total_hfest' ).text(total_hfest.toFixed(0));
    $( '.total_hfest' ).val(total_hfest.toFixed(0)); // for hidden field


    $( '.total_htrab' ).text(total_htrab.toFixed(0));
    $( '.total_htrab' ).val(total_htrab.toFixed(0)); // for hidden field


    $( '.total_medieta' ).text(total_medieta.toFixed(0));
    $( '.total_medieta' ).val(total_medieta.toFixed(0)); // for hidden field


    $( '.total_dieta' ).text(total_dieta.toFixed(0));
    $( '.total_dieta' ).val(total_dieta.toFixed(0)); // for hidden field


    $( '.total_hotel' ).text(total_hotel.toFixed(0));
    $( '.total_hotel' ).val(total_hotel.toFixed(0)); // for hidden field

 }

});
```

This is a code that when given a plus sign is adding rows, then I collect that values and keep them in a database and at the same time those values are calculated in the rows, so you will see that I work in an almost everything.

I want that when the Sunday is selected in the calendar I do not calculate the field of holidays but let me write in it to set the value, or failing to calculate if it is a Sunday but other things. All the calculations are done correctly.

I don't know why the diasem variable doesn't save me the value when I try an alert it makes me feel good.

Could someone give me a clue what happens to me?

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Comment: have you considered using moment https://momentjs.com/ ?  it come with tons of utils out of the box which will save you time

Comment: I have not used the moment.js, but I could try, you have to know what day of the week it is to be able to perform calculations according to the day of the week.

Greetings and thanks for answering